# What does 'IndexError: list index out of range' in Python mean?

Tags: python, indexing

im a beginner programmer and I don't know what this error means: 'IndexError: list index out of range'. It refers to the last line of my code. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
def sumaCuadrado(division3):
    suma = []
    if division3 == []:
        return [suma]
    else:
        suma = [division3[0]]
        return [suma] + [sumaCuadrado(division3[1:])]
```

Comment: How are you calling `sumaCuadrado()` ? are you passing a list as a parameter ?

Comment: It means you are trying to use an index at least 1 greater than the length of your list - 1 `[1,2][2] -> index error`

Comment: `division3` has less than two items. Please tell us the purpose of this of this `sum square` function.

Answer (score 4):

Exception IndexError
Raised when a sequence subscript is out of range. (Slice indices are silently truncated to fall in the allowed range; if an index is not a plain integer, TypeError is raised.) From python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError).

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are trying to access an index of the list that do not exist.
For example, the `list ['a','b','c']` have 3 indices: 0, 1 and 2.
`list[0] = 'a'` ; `list[1] = 'b'` ; `list[2] = 'c'`
If you try `list[3]` then you will get `'IndexError: list index out of range'`

Looking at your code, if the error log point to the last line, then I suggest you to check if the value of division3[1:] is what you expect. If division is not a list with at least 2 items inside then division3[1:] will raise the Index Error.